# Nested null check in a map

Tags: java, dictionary, if-statement, java-8

I am pulling a map value from an external service (which has nested maps). 
I want to get a value nested a few levels down in that map and perform some actions. 
The following works but is there a better way to do this? 
I was attempting with `Optional` but I don't think it is possible in this case as I can't pass in the method reference something like the following:

```
Optional.ofNullable(map1)
        .map(Map::get)
        ......
```

The following is the working example I am trying to amend with Optional or any other suggestions. Please advice.

```
import org.apache.commons.collections.MapUtils;

    public class A{
        private void methodA(){
            Map<String,Object> map1 = getMap(); // getMap() can return null
            if(MapUtils.isNotEmpty(map1)){
            Map<String, Map<String, String>> map2 = (Map<String, Map<String, String>>) map1.get("key2");
            if(MapUtils.isNotEmpty(map2)){
                Map<String, String> map3 = map2.get("key3");
                if(MapUtils.isNotEmpty(map3)){
                    // do something
                }
            }
        } 
    }
```

This is the closest answer I found but don't find it to be relevant for a nested map within a map within a map. 
[Java 8 nested null check for a string in a map in a list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56238423/java-8-nested-null-check-for-a-string-in-a-map-in-a-list)

Comment: Root cause for all of this - *"getMap() can return null"*. Fix that! I can second the fact that sometimes its unavoidable to use `Map<String,Object>`, but casting one of its value further to `Map<String, Map<String, String>>` is way too poor a choice.

Comment: @Naman What would have been a better alternative? Cos it comes to me in a <String, Object> from external call where its object cos the mapping is in various values of Lists and Maps and Strings. Whereas I know that the value I am extracting from that initial map is Map<String, Map<String, String>>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you looking to:

```
Optional.ofNullable(map1)
        .map(e -> (Map<String, Map<String, String>>) e.get("key2"))
        .map(e -> e.get("key3"))
        .ifPresent(e->{
            // do something
        });
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following chain:

```
Optional.ofNullable(map1)
    .map(m -> m.get("key2"))
    .map(m -> m.get("key3"))
    .ifPresent(el -> {
        // do something
    });
```